# No muestra la ventana que especifico

Tags: java, mvc

Buenas estoy haciendo un juego de cartas y en el apartado de las vistas de mi programa no me muestra de forma satisfactoria una de las ventanas, saliendo en blanco completamente sin ninguno de los componentes que contiene en su interior. Adjunto el código de las partes de mi programa. Esta desarrollado con el patrón MVC (Modelo Vista Controlador).

CLASE PRINCIPAL

```
public class El_Mentiroso {

public static void main (String[]args){
    Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
    VistaMenu vistaMenu = new VistaMenu();
    vista_CrearPartida vistaCrear = new vista_CrearPartida();
    
    new Controlador(vistaMenu, vistaCrear, modelo); }}
```

VISTA DE LA VENTANA QUE NO ME MUESTRA NADA.
Como veis, aqui tengo todos los componentes necesario que quiero que me muestre, todos sus botones, textfield, imagenes, label, etc.

```
public class vista_CrearPartida extends Frame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//VENTANA CREAR PARTIDA (COMO UNA ALTA)
public Frame ventanaCrearPartida = new Frame ("Crear Partida");
public Label nombrePartida = new Label ("Nombre de la partida:");
public TextField textoNombrePartida = new TextField (30);
public Label nombreJugador = new Label ("Nombre del creador");
public TextField textoNombreJugador = new TextField (30);
public Button botonCrearPartida = new Button ("Crear");
public Button botonSalirPartida = new Button ("cerrar");

//HERRAMIENTA PARA IMAGENES
Toolkit herramienta;
Image fondoMenu;

public vista_CrearPartida()
{
    setTitle("Crear Partida"); 
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(nombrePartida);
    add(textoNombrePartida);
    add(nombreJugador);
    add(textoNombreJugador);
    add(botonCrearPartida);
    add(botonSalirPartida);
    herramienta = getToolkit(); 
    fondoMenu = herramienta.getImage("fondoVentanas.jpg"); 
    setSize(300,380); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
    g.drawImage(fondoMenu,8,180,this); 
}}
```

CONTROLADOR, DONDE LLAMO A LA VENTANA CORRESPONDIENTE CON UN BOTON.
En este apartado, a raiz de la ventana del menu de mi programa, lo que hago es que al presionar el boton de Crear partida, lo que se supone que hago en el action performed, es llamar a la vista de mi clase crear partida. Pero lo unico que me sale es un recuadrito pequeño, sin ninguna medida en la esquina de la pantalla, obviando todos los datos que se supone que le habia añadido en su respectiva clase.

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener, WindowListener, MouseListener{
VistaMenu vistaMenu;
vista_CrearPartida vistaCrear;

Modelo modelo;
Connection conexion = null;
String informacion ="";

public Controlador(VistaMenu objvista1, vista_CrearPartida objvista2, Modelo objmodelo)
{
    this.vistaMenu = objvista1;
    this.vistaCrear = objvista2;
    this.modelo = objmodelo;
    this.vistaMenu.addWindowListener(this);
    this.vistaCrear.addWindowListener(this);
    
    //FUNCIONALIDAD MENU
    vistaMenu.ventanaMenu.addWindowListener(this);
    vistaMenu.buttonCrearPartida.addActionListener(this);
    vistaMenu.buttonMejoresJugadores.addActionListener(this);
    vistaMenu.buttonSalirMenu.addActionListener(this);  
    
    //FUNCIONALIDAD CREAR PARTIDA
    vistaCrear.ventanaCrearPartida.addWindowListener(this);
    vistaCrear.botonCrearPartida.addActionListener(this);
    vistaCrear.botonSalirPartida.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) 
{
    if(vistaMenu.buttonSalirMenu.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    else if(vistaMenu.buttonCrearPartida.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        vistaCrear.ventanaCrearPartida.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error solucionado, tenia que llamar correctamente a las vistas correspondientes dentro del controlador haciendo uso del this.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) 
{
    //CREAR PARTIDA
    if(vistaMenu.buttonCrearPartida.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaCrearP.setVisible(true);
        new VistaCrearPartida();

    }
    //INICIO DE LA PARTIDA
    if(vistaCrearP.buttonIniciarPartida.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaJugando.setVisible(true);
        new VistaJugando();
    }
    
    //CREAR JUGADOR
    else if(vistaMenu.buttonMenuCrearJugador.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaCrearJ.setVisible(true);
        new VistaCrearJugador();
        
    }
```